# Convexity of a sum

Tags: convex-analysis

I am revisiting a book and came across the following problem:

---

> Let $$\begin{align*}
>             f(\boldsymbol{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{r} |x|_{[i]}
>         \end{align*}$$
> where $\vert x \vert_{[i]}$ is the $i$ th largest component of $|x_1|, \cdots, |x_n|$. Is $f$ convex?

---

I have been attempting to do this for hours using the second-order condition of convexity ($\nabla^2 f(x) \ge 0$) as well as trying to approach it as a set and prove the convexity of a set.

The fact it is a sum is completely throwing me off. Would appreciate some help with this. Thank you.

Comment: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2022/11/sum-of-k-largest.html

Comment: Where did you come across this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is not differentiable, so going the Hessian route is probably not a fruitful approach.

Let $S$ be the set of $n$ dimensional vectors with $\pm 1$ in $r$ places and zero elsewhere.

Note that $f(x) = \max_{s \in S} s^T x$ and the $\max$ of a finite number of convex functions is convex.

Establishing equality is straightforward. Show that
$f(x) \ge s^T x$ for any $s\in S$ and then show that for any $x$ there must be some $s \in S$ that achieves equality.

**Elaboration**:

To establish the equality $f(x) = \max_{s \in S} s^T x$ ,
first pick any $s \in S$. Note that $s$ is zero except for $r$ entries that are $\pm 1$.

Since $f(x)$ is the sum of the largest $r$ components of $x$ we must have $f(x) \ge s^T x$ (remember that $|x_k| \ge \pm x_k$).

To show equality, let $i_1,...,i_r$ be the indices of the $r$ largest elements of $|x|$, and let
$s = \sum_{k=1}^r (\operatorname{sgn} x_{i_k}) e_{i_k}$. Note that $s \in S$ and
$s^T x = \sum_{k=1}^r | x_{i_k} | = f(x)$.

Comment: Took my a while to understand the first 2 parts. Could you please explain a little more about establishing equality? I don't quite understand how to do this/why we are doing this? Thank you

Comment: @Ronharrison I added an elaboration.